# partial view in mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I would like to sum table column for view model is

```
public class ColumnTotal {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal ColumnOne { get; set; }
    public decimal ColumnTwo { get; set; }
    public decimal ColumnThree { get; set; }
}
```

My home controller of columntotal method looks like this

```
 public IActionResult ColumnTotal()
    {
        var query = _context.REHPData.Include(r => r.BudgetYear).GroupBy(r => r.BudgetYearlyAllocation.ID).Select(s => new ColumnTotal
        {
            ID = s.Key,
            ColumnOne = s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTeen),
            ColumnTwo = s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTwo),
            ColumnThree = s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaFour)

        }).ToList();
        return View(query);

    }
```

MY partial view _test.cshtml looks like this

```
  @model RenewableEnergyProjcet.Models.CalculationViewModels.ColumnTotal
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ColumnOne)</td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ColumnTwo)</td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ColumnThree)</td>
    </tr>
```

my report.chtml looks like this

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Budget Result Table ";
}

<h2>Budgets Result Table  </h2>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
       <td>Some Columns -----</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            some data----
        </tr>
    }

        <tr>
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_test"); //how to call this partial _test.chtml
        </tr>

</table>
```

please how to call partial _test.chtml from in method.

Comment: have you written the action that returns the partial view?

Comment: i don't understand sir please help me

Comment: I dont have much experience in core, but if i was to do it as in mvc then you would need a controller action like this 
`public PartialViewResult Test()
            {
                return PartialView("_test",new YourViewModel());
            }`

Comment: and in the main view, instead of using @await use:-- `@Html.RenderPartial("_test",YourViewModelObject)`

Comment: @paingsoethu2015, are you sure that you need this partial view just for showing calculated footer? May be try a variant of combining two requests? First is your query that return main table, and second for footer, and combine them using `Concat` or `Union`. If so, then there is no need of partial view and sending second query to server.

Comment: Yes, as Hemid suggests this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you simply want a summary footer why not just do the Sum() in razor since you already have the collection?

Answer (score 0):

In Action that fill report.chtml call too the query that you use in ColumnTotal() action and send it to the view and in the view use RenderPartial() to call the view.

```
public IActionResult report()
{
    ViewData["ColumnTotal"] = _context.REHPData.Include(r => r.BudgetYear).GroupBy(r => r.BudgetYearlyAllocation.ID).Select(s => new ColumnTotal
    {
        ID = s.Key,
        ColumnOne = s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTeen),
        ColumnTwo = s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTwo),
        ColumnThree = s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaFour)

    }).ToList();
    return View("report");

}
```

An in the view do something like this.

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_test",ViewData["ColumnTotal"])
```

Comment: my problems is new post and advice sirs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987400/how-to-relationship-five-table-and-gropby-and-sum-row-and-column-and-where-asp